# How to upload react-native 0.54.3 android Apk to play store? it is throwing google play 64-bit requirements error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-play, google-play-services

we had developed react-native 0.54.3 app and uploaded to playstore.  now we are going to update android app now.
it is throwing.
[image]

**can we update react-native 0.54.3  apk to playstore? is it possible?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit some files, take a look at this post https://medium.com/@andriidrozdov/reactnative-and-android-64-bit-new-google-play-market-rules-what-to-do-584b067d6f1a.

If you want to upgrade, use this tool: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ it will help you.